# Adding Code Other Than Header/Footer in Ghost

Tags: ghost-blog

I want to make a few additions to the homepage. Can I add my own code to Ghost for this? I was only able to add to the header and footer sections in the code section. Is there another feature like this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dzbb.png)